# What is the complexity of strided slice in Tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, time-complexity, space-complexity

I am wondering what is the complexity of the strided slice function in Tensorflow. Obviously, it is not as computationally intensive as a Convolution 2D, but it's certainly not free neither. I'm not even sure talking of complexity for this operation is meaningful since there is no addition or multiplication performed.
To be concrete, let's say I have a 10x3x3x10 tensor `foo` and I want to perform `bar=foo[3:5,:,:,4:5]`. How would you evaluate the complexity of the operation (both in terms of space and time)?

Comment: It certainly depends on what do you factor in in your calculation of complexity. Obviously, there are no floating point operations involved, but there is the cost of creating the new tensor. As far as I know, TensorFlow tensors cannot be strided, so I suppose this involves a copy of the values. So I'd say the complexity is linear on the total size of the output (both in time and memory). Fwiw, the striding is done by Eigen. You can find it in [`TensorMorphing.h`](https://bitbucket.org/eigen/eigen/src/default/unsupported/Eigen/CXX11/src/Tensor/TensorMorphing.h), although it is not an easy read.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [TF_Strided_Slice](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/strided_slice) Operation and [Conv2D](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Conv2D?version=nightly) Operation and then  evaluate the complexity of those Operations using **`Profiling`** in **`Keras Callback`**.

Corresponding code is mentioned below:

```
log_dir="logs/profile/" + datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S")

tensorboard_callback = tf.keras.callbacks.TensorBoard(log_dir=log_dir, histogram_freq=1, profile_batch = 3)

model.fit(train_data,
          steps_per_epoch=20,
          epochs=5, 
          callbacks=[tensorboard_callback])
```